# Drawing electrical diagram using circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I looked at the documentation and examples on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/), but [`circuitikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) is hard to get the hang of.

I am trying to create

[image: wanted]

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (-.5, 0) to[L, l = L] (1.4, 0)
           to[R, l = R] (5, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

but the spacing is weird, and I can't seem to figure out how to set it up.

Comment: For some reason, your picture doesn't appear properly on the page. Am I the only one experiencing a problem? I uploaded a cropped version of it; now everything is fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I too find the `circuitikz` documentation a bit lacking, but you learn a lot from inspecting the examples. A quick [`[circuitikz]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuitikz?sort=votes&pageSize=50) search on the site will lead you to more examples. Moreover, a few additional `circuitikz` examples are available at [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/circuitikz/).

Regarding spacing, my main piece of advice (which applies to any vector-graphics package, really) is to parameterise everything at the beginnning; refrain from using "magic numbers". Your circuit will be far easier to adjust; moving things around will be a breeze. See below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{article}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=2]
    \def\xPortLeft{0}
    \def\yTerminalBottom{0}
    \def\yL{1.5}
    \def\xL{1}
    \def\xR{1.75}
    \def\xC{2.25}
    \def\xPortRight{3}
    % left loop
    \draw                               (\xPortLeft,\yL)
            to[L=$L$, o-]               (\xL, \yL)
            to[R=$R$]                   (\xR, \yL)
            to[short]                   (\xC,\yL)
            to[C, l_=$C$,*-*]           (\xC,\yTerminalBottom)
            to[short,i=$i(t)$]          (\xPortLeft,\yTerminalBottom)
            to[open,v^>=$v_1(t)$,o-o]   (\xPortLeft,\yL);
    % right branch
    \draw                               (\xC,\yL)
            to[short]                   (\xPortRight,\yL)
            to[open,v^=$v_2(t)$,o-o]    (\xPortRight,\yTerminalBottom)
            to[short]                   (\xC,\yTerminalBottom);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Jubobs, I tried to use your commands in a \documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,convert = false]{article}, but I have problems with  this command to[open,v^>=$v_1(t)$,o-o], in specific with "^".

Could you help me? If you need any information, you can ask me.

Answer (score 8):

This is how. Define `(x,y)` coordinate for each circuit node (2cm separation is fairly good in general), then use `to[options]` to connect all of the nodes, where `options` can be R, L, C, open (circuit), short (circuit), l(abel)=, v=, i=, for label/current/voltage name respectively. Variants such as `v^`, `v_` and equivalents are designed to put labels on either side of circuit elements. As to the current loop for KVL, this solution uses `amssymb` package with node technique to achieve that. By default, currents are labeled on each branch as shown in the capacitor branch.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[convert = false, border=10pt,]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (-.5, 2) to[L, l = $L$] (2, 2) to [R, l = $R$] (4, 2) to [short](6,2)
(4,2) to[C,l=$C$] (4,0)
(-0.5,2) to [open, v=$v_1(t)$,o-o](-0.5,0)
(6,2) to [open, v=$v_2(t)$,o-o] (6,0)   % use v^=$V_2$, if you want it on the right side.
(-0.5,0)--(6,0)
(1.5,1) node[scale=3]{$\circlearrowright$}
(1.5,1) node{$i_1$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

If PSTricks is allowed, you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

% PSTricks.
\usepackage{
  pst-circ,
  pst-bspline,
  pstricks-add
}
\psset{unit = 0.8}

% Width and height of the diagram.
\def\width{12}
\def\height{6}

% Calculating width and height of picture.
\usepackage{xfp}
\newcommand*\Width{\fpeval{\width+0.4}}
\newcommand*\Height{\fpeval{\height+0.82}}

\begin{document}

% Drawing.
\begin{pspicture}(-0.4,-0.05)(\Width,\Height)
  % Coordinates for the ends of the wires.
  \pnodes{P}%
    (0,0)(0,0)% Doubled to let the nodes start from P1 instead of P0.
    (\fpeval{0.70*\width},0)%
    (\width,0)%
    (0,\height)%
    (\fpeval{0.35*\width},\height)%
    (\fpeval{0.70*\width},\height)
    (\width,\height)
  % Wires and components.
  \wire[arrows = o-o](P1)(P3)
  \coil[arrows = o-](P4)(P5){$L$}
  \resistor[arrows = -o, dipolestyle = zigzag](P5)(P6){$R$}
  \wire[arrows = o-o](P6)(P7)
  \capacitor[arrows = *-*](P2)(P6){$C$}
  % Labels.
  \uput[90](P1){$-$}
  \uput[90](P3){$-$}
  \uput[270](P4){$+$}
  \uput[270](P7){$+$}
 {\psset{linestyle = none}
  \pcline(P1)(P4)
  \ncput*{$v_1(t)$}
  \pcline(P3)(P7)
  \ncput*{$v_2(t)$}}
  % Direction of the current.
  \psBspline[arrows = ->]%
       (\fpeval{0.7*\width-3.0},\fpeval{\height-1})%
       (\fpeval{0.7*\width-1.2},\fpeval{\height-1})%
       (\fpeval{0.7*\width-1.2},1)%
       (\fpeval{0.7*\width-3.0},1)
  \rput(\fpeval{0.7*\width-2.2},\fpeval{\height/2}){$i(t)$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Here, [`pst-circ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ) is for drawing the electrical components, [`pst-bspline`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-bspline) is for drawing the curved arrow, and [`pstricks-add`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-add) is for setting the labels.

Width and height of the diagram can be chosen freely, and calculation of the corresponding width and height of the picture is automated.

Note: The advantage of using Herbert Voß' package `pst-circ` for a drawing like this is that all the macros are (more or less) self-explanatory, so the code is really easy to edit if needed. Also, the [documentation](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-circ/doc/pst-circ-doc.pdf) has a lot of examples.

Comment: +1 for PSTricks. I believe that your code can still be simplified. I am doing it...

Answer (score 6):

Just another solution with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\def\Tension(#1)(#2)#3{\uput[-90](#1){$+$}\uput[90](#2){$-$}\rput([nodesep=1.5]{#2}#1){#3}}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,1)(9,-4)
    \pnodes(0,0){A}(3,0){B}(6,0){C}(8,0){D}([offset=-3]A){A'}([offset=-3]B){B'}([offset=-3]C){C'}([offset=-3]D){D'}
    \coil[arrows=o-,labeloffset=20pt](A)(B){$L$}
    \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag,labeloffset=18pt](B)(C){$R$}
    \wire[arrows=-o](C)(D)
    \capacitor[arrows=*-*,labeloffset=-24pt](C)(C'){$C$}
    \wire[arrows=o-o](A')(D')
    \Tension(A)(A'){$v_1(t)$}
    \Tension(D)(D'){$v_2(t)$}
    \pcbar[linearc=20pt,arm=50pt]{->}([offset=-20pt]B)([offset=20pt]B')
    \nbput[labelsep=12pt]{$i(t)$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

```
    % \the following tensions don't work temporarily
    %\tension[tensionstyle=pm](A)(A'){$v_1(t)$}
    %\tension[tensionstyle=pm](D)(D'){$v_2(t)$}
```