# Tighter capacitor plates in CircuiTikZ

Tags: tikz-styles, circuitikz

The gap between the plates of `CircuiTikZ`'s default capacitor symbol is quite spacious. I'd like it to be less so, perhaps by a factor of 2/3 or 1/2.

You can see the difference between what I want and what `CircuiTikZ` produces in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154684/drawing-electrical-diagram-using-circuitikz): the question has a photo of a capacitor symbol that's nice and tight, whilst the answer has the typical wide-ish spacing of the two parallel capacitor plates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

Thanks to @rmano, the maintainer of `circuitikz`, since v1.4.1 a new option `capacitors/width=<num>` is added (and documented), which has the initial value `0.2` and will influence *all* the capacitor components. For more info, see the package manual, sec. 4.3.3 "Capacitors customizations".

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0, 0) to[C, l=$0.2$] +(1, 0);
  
  \ctikzset{capacitors/width=.15} % initially 0.2
  \draw (2, 0) to[C, l=$0.15$] +(1, 0);
  
  \ctikzset{capacitors/width=.1}
  \draw (4, 0) to[C, l=$0.1$] +(1, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Output is the same as below.

**Original:**

That space between two parallel capacitor plates is configurable through `\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/width=<num>}`, with an initial value `0.2`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0, 0) to[C, l=$0.2$] +(1, 0);
  
  \ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/width=.15} % initially 0.2
  \draw (2, 0) to[C, l=$0.15$] +(1, 0);
  
  \ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/width=.1}
  \draw (4, 0) to[C, l=$0.1$] +(1, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I learnt the key name from the source file `pgfcircbipoles.tex` (for `circuitikz` v1.4.0). The key used above is [defined here](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/blob/0e1fa16ff5638636b7dc454ecfb7864db5d9b1c5/tex/pgfcircbipoles.tex#L722) and [used in `capacitor` here](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/blob/0e1fa16ff5638636b7dc454ecfb7864db5d9b1c5/tex/pgfcircbipoles.tex#L741-L757). From the package manual, sec. 3.1.4.3 *Shape of the components*, this seems to be the suggested way of learning.

Comment: That `0.1` is exactly what I was looking for. You rock!

Comment: Yes --- that is the way to do it. Maybe I should add a style key for changing all the capacitors-like width together... or at list describe the keys in the manual.

Comment: @Rmano Having the keys as well as their initial values documented is preferable, but it need more efforts :)

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ yes, I was just preparing something like that. A global setting for all capacitor is not advisable because each capacitor is different. Next release will have it!

Comment: Discussion open on: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/566

Comment: Notice that a new `capacitors/width` style key has been added to 1.4.1. Thanks for the suggestions @Mew @muzimuzhiZ

Comment: @Rmano @Mew A new example using `capacitors/width` has been added to my answer.